# How to select case-insensitive JSONB keys in PostgreSQL (9.4+)

Tags: json, postgresql, postgresql-9.4, jsonb

## Setup (PostgreSQL 9.4+)

Assume I have a table `product`:

```
create table product
(
    attributes jsonb
);
```

with data:

```
insert into product (attributes) 
values ('{"Color": "Red"}'), 
       ('{"color": "White"}'),
       ('{"COLOR": "Blue"}');
```

## Question

How do I select all records' `color` attribute in PostgreSQL 9.4+? Since the keys differ in casing, I am unable to use this syntax:

```
select 
    attributes->>'color' as color
from product;
```

My expected output would be:

```
Red
White
Blue
```

## Possible Solution

I also tried using this syntax (works but feels hacky):

```
select 
    coalesce(
        attributes->>'color', 
        attributes->>'Color', 
        attributes->>'COLOR') as color 
from product;
```

Is this possible? I can see that it might conflict should you have `color` and `Color` keys on the same object, so I would not be surprised if this is not a thing.

References:

- [PostgreSQL JSON Functions and Operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-json.html)

Comment: Perfectly worded question, should serve as a model.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should extract the pairs `(key, value)` to use the function `lower()`

```
select value as color
from product, jsonb_each(attributes)
where lower(key) = 'color';
```

or using a more verbose syntax:

```
select value as color
from product
cross join jsonb_each(attributes)
where lower(key) = 'color';
```

This `cross join` is a *lateral join*, the function `jsonb_each()` is executed once for each row from `product.`

Comment: `jsonb_each()` is the type of thing I was looking for but had no idea existed, thanks! There's also `json_each()`, those return `value` as `jsonb` and `json` respectively; while `jsonb_each_text()` and `json_each_text()` return `value` as `text` (unsurprisingly). `key` is always `text`. All from [postgres docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-json.html)

Comment: This just saved me from what would have otherwise been hours of me banging my head against the wall! And it was so easy to use! Thank you so much!!